# Pasting into Access from Excel - Non-numeric entries don't get through

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Every once and awhile a user will complain about my Access application losing fields. I've found out that they are right. Access in certain situations will simply drop accepting data from a copy and paste operation for a certain field, consistently.

It is almost as if Access thinks that the pasted data is only numeric data, then onces it sees Alpha it attempts to cast to a number, fails then ignores it.

The image below is *not* the custom application but a new Access file, where I just copy and paste the Excel data raw. I've looked at the raw clipboard data using http://www.peterbuettner.de/develop/tools/clipview/ but I do not see any obvious issues or format issues.

Thoughts?

[image: Test Application and Data]

Comment: Found a similar description at http://www.accessforums.net/access/copy-paste-csv-access-2010-a-20031.html.  Based on that response, you should develop an import so this glitch won't come up.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is a confirmed bug then if it went that far back. I'll consider the import wizard, but it may not work in my process use-case.

Comment: +1 for citing the utility to view clipboard data.  Besides nifty, that constitutes research!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a 'paste special' operation and paste as plain text. For ease of use, I recommend pinning the 'paste special' button to the Quick Access toolbar.

Sometimes Access gets confused when you let it guess what you're pasting. Pasting as plain text is the best way to force it to work.

**Edit**

Example Code for Right Click Menu

```
Public Function CreateGeneralClipBoardMenu()
    On Error Resume Next
    CommandBars("GeneralClipboardMenu").Delete

    Dim cmb As Office.CommandBar

    Set cmb = CommandBars.Add("GeneralClipboardMenu", msoBarPopup, False, False)

        With cmb
            .Controls.Add msoControlButton, 21, , , True  ' Cut
            .Controls.Add msoControlButton, 19, , , True  ' Copy
            .Controls.Add msoControlButton, 755, , , True  ' Paste Special
        End With

    Set cmb = Nothing
End Function
```

The ID# 755 is a magic number for Paste Special, and I found it on this list: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213552

Where to set it in Access 2013. Access Options - Current Database - Shortcut Ribbon Bar

[image: Access Options - Current Database - Shortcut Ribbon Bar]

Comment: I'm using the Access Runtime, so the typical right-click context menus are not available.  I used my own right-click menu, but the paste operation command is given by Access.  As far as I know there is no paste special.

Comment: @IsraelLopez - can you test my suggestion with the new Access file that you created to demonstrate the issue? At least then we'll know if my method works under normal circumstances :-)

Comment: Actually paste special works, but works differently.  It takes the first row as headers, but the rest seemed to paste fine.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell this a recognized glitch.  If true, then all you can do is work around it, which unfortunately affects your end-users instead of just yourself.

Found a similar description at [accessforums.net/access/copy-paste-csv-access-2010-a-20031.html](http://accessforums.net/access/copy-paste-csv-access-2010-a-20031.html).

**Hmmm.**  So what happens if the data from Excel is sorted such that one of the alpha-numeric entries is on the top row?

Comment: But hey, give it a day to see what the smart people say!

Comment: I've noticed that it works once, but not consistently enough for the users to understand what is happening.  But I guess I am right that Access is attempting to guess the data type, but fails later on in the data stream.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put a header[string so that access will consider all the following data as string] before copying the data. insert new column above your header then copy/paste your data including the header and empty column to your access table.